# Why did my cat leave/return?

Tags: cats

Recently, my cat returned from a 3 month 'vacation'. We know her to Run off for a day or two, but never that long. What strikes me is that she did come back. So, Any ideas?

She is a standard domestic cat, about 6 years old, spaded at 3. We did have some new animals shortly before she left, but that was about a month before she bugged out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

She got lost. Or someone else adopted her for a while. Or some other cat took over her territory and it was a while before she felt safe coming home. Or...

Comment: A doubt she was lost, since we found her minutes away. Possibly the others though.